# How do I create a new hash of values for a condition?

Tags: ember.js

Let's say I have photos.

I am iterating through my photos in my `photos.hbs`

```
{{#each}}
 {{title}}
 {{src}}
{{/each}}
```

I'm pulling all my photos from a fixture. My route is just doing `@store.find('photo')`

Now let's say I want to also show featured photos. Which is just a flag on an individual photo object. So we have `title, src, featured`.

In my controller how do I specify a filtered collection of photos based on featured being true?

In my view I'd like to add

```
{{#each featuredPhoto}}
  {{title}}
  {{src}}
  {{featured}}
{{/each}}
```

that way I can view all photos + featured photos in a separate collection on the same page. How would I do this?

If I were using Rails I'd just do `@photos = Photo.where(featured: true)`. And then I would iterate over the photos instance variable in my view. Unfortunately I can't find anything to be that easy here?

Comment: So you're not using Rails? Why is this tagged with ruby-on-rails.

Comment: Removed RoR tag as it was invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
App.PhotoController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  featuredPhoto: (function() {
    return this.filterBy('featured');
  }).property('content')
});
```